# Non-coplanar transfer in GMAT

Tags: mission-design, gmat

I am trying to use GMAT to do a non-coplanar transfer between 2 circular orbits.
In which the first orbit would have a 0º inclination, and the final orbit would have a 28º inclination. And the objective for the transfer orbit would be for it to begin with a 0º inclination and end up with a 28º inclination, this is for it to change inclination during the orbit. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to perform simple plane change maneuver in which all orbital elements are unchanged (except the inclination) then you must perform it either on the ascending node or descending node.

Use target command vary element 1 and element 2 of satellite and then propagate to the node. There is no direct way of propagating spacecraft to these nodes in GMAT. What you can do is that if the satellites name is 'A' then propagate the spacecraft 'A' until its Right Ascension becomes equal to the RAAN.
Hope this will help